# How to create a shortcut to a printer programmatically?

Tags: c#, printers, shortcut-file

Normally you can create a shortcut to a printer from right click menu of printer itself.

Is there any other way around?

I tried using IWshShortcut with following parameter as targetpath

```
"Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers\MyPrinter"
```

It creates a shortcut but its not valid

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IWshShortcut` can't create a shortcut to a printer because it supports only file system targets. To create a shortcut to a printer requires digging into the shell namespace, which is a very advanced topic. You need to get the `LPITEMIDLIST` for the `FOLDERID_PrintersFolder`, bind to that folder to get the `IShellFolder`, use `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` to enumerate the printers, decide which printer you like (perhaps by inspecting its name with `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf`), and then use `IShellLink::SetIDList` to target a shell link to that printer. I gave you the magic words so you can do some searches and learn more about them, but I'm not going to try to teach the shell namespace on SO.

Comment: I would like to know that if i create a shortcut manually through rightclick options on my printer, it creates a normal shortcut file with .lnk extension, and even show me target path like i mentioned. Why is that? I mean it does seems like created with shell extension.

Comment: When you open the Printers folder, the Printers folder obtains the `LPITEMIDLIST` for the `FOLDERID_PrintersFolder`, binds to the folder to get its `IShellFolder`, uses `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` to list all the printers and display them (using the name returned by `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf`). When you right-click one of them and click "Create shortcut", the Printers folder uses `IShellLink::SetIDList` to target a shell link to that printer.